# How can I schedule a task within my telegram application to message some chat every 5 minutes?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I read the python-telegram-bot documentation about the job_queue [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/discussions/3725)

It is written that

```
from telegram.ext import ContextTypes, Application

async def callback_minute(context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):await context.bot.send_message(chat_id='@examplechannel', text='One message every minute')

application = Application.builder().token('TOKEN').build()job_queue = application.job_queue

job_minute = job_queue.run_repeating(callback_minute, interval=60, first=10)

application.run_polling()
```

Yet in my short example

```
from telegram.ext import Application

application = Application.builder().token("TOKEN").build()

job_queue = application.job_queue
```

The job_queue is None, so I can't execute run_repeating on the queue.
I can't seem to find a working example on the current version.
I know my application is correct because when I added handlers to connect to telegram it was working. I managed to communicate back and forth in the chat.

I also know that I can use the following in the task to send the message to the chat

`await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Testing evaluation")`

Can someone give me a working example on how I can schedule a tasks to send the message to some chat at an interval of time such as 60 seconds.

python-telegram-bot version I am working with is 20.4
python version is 3.9

Comment: this site is for answering questions, not for providing code ... please remove the request from your question

Comment: I asked a specific question, how can I schedule a task in the telegram application using Python code?  

I have provided a simple example to make the person who would try to help me have an easier time. 

How is this not a question ?

Comment: I did not say that it is not a question ... it is the request for a working example that should not be made ... the answer to your question may simply be an addition of one command to your existing code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please have a look at

- the [wiki page on `JobQueue`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions---JobQueue)
- the documentation of the [`JobQueue` class](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html)
- the [`timerbot`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/examples.html#examples-timerbot) example

All of these references include one important note: In order to use the `JobQueue`, you'll have to install PTB with an optional dependency: `pip install "python-telegram-bot[job-queue]"` - See also the readmes section on [dependencies in PTB](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/index.html#dependencies-their-versions).

Note that PTB issues warnings about missing optional dependencies wherever possible. I'm pretty sure that you'll find a note on that if you carefully read your console output ;)

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.